# CPLEX program with absolute values in Python

Tags: python, cplex

I need to write a PL in python and solve it with CPLEX library but i'm a beginner and therefore i don't know how to write it in Python.

The program is:

```
MIN ΣΣ abs(Ui - Uj)        with i = 1, j = i + 1
subject to:
    Ui = Σ Wj * Xji        ∀i
    Xji is 0/1 integer     ∀i,j with i < j
    0.0 =< Ui <= T
```

Comment: And what did you try, that didn't work?

Comment: i don't know how to write the objective function with absolute values in Python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

abs is very easy to use with docplex.

Let me change a bit the [zoo example](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/making-optimization-simple-python-alex-fleischer/) to use abs

Suppose I want to get as close as possible to cost 3900

```
from docplex.mp.model import Model

mdl = Model(name='buses')
nbbus40 = mdl.integer_var(name='nbBus40')
nbbus30 = mdl.integer_var(name='nbBus30')
mdl.add_constraint(nbbus40*40 + nbbus30*30 >= 300, 'kids')
mdl.minimize(mdl.abs(nbbus40*500 + nbbus30*400-3900))

mdl.solve()

for v in mdl.iter_integer_vars():
    print(v," = ",v.solution_value)
```

Comment: Thanks, very easy with docplex.